# Excel worksheet does not record values entered into input boxes (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have been teaching myself VBA code for the past couple months and am trying to practice it by helping my family with their general store business. I decided to create a simple inventory spreadsheet with 'name' (Column A), 'price' (Column B), and 'discount-worthy' (Column C) as the column headings. In order to make it easier/less tedious for my parents to enter information into the spreadsheet (something they've complained about), I decided the best thing to do would be to give them three input boxes (one for each column) per row, before iterating to the next row and doing the same thing. Below is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub InsertValues()

Dim name As String, price As Currency, discounted As String
Dim rga As Range, rgv As Range, rgc As Range
Dim i As Integer, lasti As Integer

name = InputBox("Please enter a name.")
price = InputBox("Please enter a price.")
discounted = InputBox("Please specify if there's potential for a discount to be attached.")

lasti = i + 1
For i = 2 To lasti
    Set rga = Cells(i,1)
        rga.Value = name
    Set rgv = Cells(i,2)
        rgv.Value = price
    Set rgc = Cells(i,3)
        rgc.Value = discounted
Next i
End Sub
```

The problem I have is that when I enter some values into the input boxes, the values are not being appearing in the cells. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong -- does it have something to do with the for loop and/or .value term? I included the 'lasti' variable so that I could have the user automatically advance to the next row and enter in information for the next product. I hope this makes sense -- I'm a high school student and have never really taught myself something like this before.

Comment: `Debug.Print lasti` ... it equals 1, so your loop never runs.

Comment: That answer helps, thank you so much!!